# Execute a method every time a prop changes (watch vs v-bind:key)

Tags: vue.js

I want a function of the child to execute every time the prop sent to the child is changed. I've found two methods to do this:

Method 1: `watch` won't execute, but `created` executes every time `showing` is changing.

```
<block-post v-bind:title="showing" v-bind:key="showing" v-if="showing"></block-post>
```

```
watch: { 
    title: function(newVal, oldVal) { // watch it
         console.log('Prop changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal)
         this.load()
    }
    },
created: function(){
    this.load();
},
```

Method 2: `created` is executed once and `watch` executes whenever `showing` changes.

```
<block-post v-bind:title="showing" v-if="showing"></block-post>
```

```
watch: { 
    title: function(newVal, oldVal) { // watch it
         console.log('Prop changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal)
         this.load()
    }
},
created: function(){
    this.load();
},
```

Example function to be executed:

```
method: {
load: function() {
   console.log("Hello");
   }
}
```

How come it is like that? Is it because of `v-bind:key`? And if it is, then why? What is actually the function of `v-bind:key`. I tried to search that up, and I find it mostly connected to `v-for`.
For me Method 2 sounds more correct. Any explanations is appreciated as I'm quite new to Vue and I am currently trying to learn it.

Comment: What is ```this.load```? Is that a vue method? And if so, why you define it like that? Also do you use ```v-for``` in your code?

Comment: `this.load` is indeed a vue method. No idea, why I wrote it like a normal Javascript function. I've edited it now! Thank you for pointing that out. And no I don't use `v-for` at all. I followed an example from my lecture `v-bind:key` was used. @hamid-davodi

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#key

Comment: @MichalLevý "_It can also be used to force replacement of an element/component instead of reusing it._". Oh, this part really explains it then. That it can be used this way. I had no idea. Thank you so much!